# How to kill chromium snap from CLI?

Tags: snap, chromium, 22.04

Chromium is installed as a snap. When it's running, how do I kill the process from command line? Like killall or pkill.
This didn't work:

```
sudo snap stop chromium
error: snap "chromium" has no services
```

Comment: `killall` is all I use and it works...  Did you provide the correct path?

Comment: You are using the wrong command. `sudo snap stop <package-name>` WON'T kill all processes started from that software. That's not what the command is intended to do. It will only stop *services* (chromium runs no services). See `man snap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested here on my laptop and it worked.
Try it:

```
sudo killall chrome
```

Comment: I tried sudo killall chromium... Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think it'd work; thus used it on my *kinetic* system.... alas all my `chromium` windows disappeared just as you said...

Comment: @minyves you can see the path to a process by filtering keywords in htop. The name to use in killall command is the word after the last slash /

Comment: @guiverc it's kind of confusing. We can use the same command to kill google-chrome.

Comment: Yeah, you've given me something to explore (*when I have time*) to work out why it's done that way; but yep it works.  You got my upvote anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Once running, the process launched from an app installed as a snap, is a process like any other. Use the usual tools.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is:

```
pkill --oldest chrome
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/131021/1690541)